# TextInputLayout removes EditText style after setting setError property to null

Tags: android

I want to use TextInputLayout with my new app. I have such layout

```
***
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/text_color"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintTextAppearance.TextInputLayout"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorTextAppearance.TextInputLayout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border_radius"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_acc"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
 ***
```

On my activity i have validation as below:

```
    private boolean validatePassword() {
            if (inputPassword.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                inputLayoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_password));
                requestFocus(inputPassword);
                return false;
            } else {
                inputLayoutPassword.setError(null);// it removes @drawable/edit_text_border_radius style from EditText
                inputLayoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);      
            }

            return true;
     }
```

Not it works correctly. but as if you notices i have declared @drawable/edit_text_border_radius resource for EditText. And if first time i do not fill password field it is going to change it is background color to red. As it is default color for TextInputLayout error span. But then if i fill same field with some values then red error span disappears but EditText element forget it is background resource(@drawable/edit_text_border_radius) set to it before.

Comment: actually where you are setting both color

Comment: @Sree , sorry which colors?

Comment: i mean red and another

Comment: Red color for error span is coming from TextInputLayout standard color. Another color after calling setError(null) i can not understand where it comes

Comment: so better set the color for the text and background what ever you want once again if you find a entry

Comment: But i think it must be done automatically. Because if i fill field it hides error span. It's good. But it would not to change background color of EditText that i have not declared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90879/discussion-between-aemloviji-and-sree).

Comment: do you get answer of this quistain?

Comment: do you got the solution of this??

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've found a solution to your problem, but I just ran into the same issue.

Digging into the `TextInputLayout` source, especially the logic around clearing the error message, it looks like the `EditText` gets it's background color filter cleared (in my case, it was turning black).

The quick and dirty solution I've come up with in the mean time is to just manually reset the background filter to the desired color:

```
private boolean validatePassword() {
    if (inputPassword.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        inputLayoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_password));
        requestFocus(inputPassword);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutPassword.setError(null);// it removes @drawable/edit_text_border_radius style from EditText
        inputLayoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);

        // manually resetting the background color filter of edit text
        if(inputLayoutPassword.getEditText() != null) {
            if(inputLayoutPassword.getEditText().getBackground() != null) {
                inputLayoutPassword.getEditText()
                    .getBackground()
                    .setColorFilter(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.some_color),
                        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN
                    );
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```